# Couldn't connect to service inside docker container

Tags: docker

I try to run command inside docker container like this:

```
openssl s_client  -connect 127.0.0.1:4443
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

in the next step I try to detect ip for docker image from `/etc/hosts`:

```
172.18.0.2  aaf6fa11bc88
```

then I try to connect inside containers to this IP and got:

```
openssl s_client  -connect 172.18.0.2:4443
connect: Connection refused
```

not sure why I could connect to `127.0.0.1` and couldn't connect by IP  `172.18.0.2` which has been placed in `/etc/hosts` file  in Docker container?

I have flashed iptables:

```
iptables -F and iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

There is ifconfig output:

```
ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:12:00:02  
          inet addr:172.18.0.2  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5038 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12755512 (12.1 MiB)  TX bytes:278694 (272.1 KiB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:5332 (5.2 KiB)  TX bytes:5332 (5.2 KiB)
```

app is running inside container:

```
ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:01 python db_adapter.py
  284 pts/0    Ss     0:00 /bin/bash
  315 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

I couldnt connect to db_adapter using ip like `172.18.0.2` but could connect to `127.0.0.1` (maybe problem with db_adapter?)

There is output :

```
docker-compose ps
       Name                      Command               State           Ports         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_db-adapter_1   python db_adapter.py             Up      0.0.0.0:4443->4443/tcp
```

There is docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  fake-s3:
    image: fake-s3

  db-adapter:
    image: db-adapter
    ports:
    - "4443:4443"
  mail:
    image: mail
    volumes:
    depends_on:
      - fake-s3
      - db-adapter
    links:
      - db-adapter

volumes:
    mailproxy:
```

Comment: yes app is running inside container

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile?

Comment: seems problem with app :

Comment: netstat -a shows only 127.0.0.1:4443 for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your python application `db-adapter` binds only to `localhost`. That's why you can access it only via `127.0.0.1:4443` and only inside a container. You need to find a way to bind it to `0.0.0.0`. After that you can access it on `172.18.0.2:4443` inside container and by `127.0.0.1:4443` from host.